# How do you get a Rails project to start with index.html.erb instead of index.html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, start-page

My `index.html` page for my project needs some Ruby code so I need to change it to a `.erb` extension. How do I configure Rails to identify the `index.html.erb` file as the starting page of the project instead of the `index.html` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the `map.root` path in your `config/routes.rb` file.

```
map.root :controller => "blogs"

# This would recognize http://www.example.com/ as
params = { :controller => 'blogs', :action => 'index' }

# and provide these named routes
root_url   # => 'http://www.example.com/'
root_path  # => ''
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html

Comment: Thanks. So this would require the index.html.erb page to exist in the views folder associated with a particular controller - I have to move it out of the public folder where my current index.html file is?

Comment: Yup. I should have mentioned that you must delete the default index.html file out of your public folder before the change I listed above will take effect :)

Answer (score 2):

public/index.html is a flat file, and doesn't go through any templating (everything in /public/ is like this.)

If you want templating on your index page, you need to run the request through a controller and a view.  You can map the root URL of your application to a controller with map.root:

```
map.root :controller => 'home'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do root to:

config/routes.rb

```
    root to: 'index.html.erb'
```

Be sure to delete index.html file

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are now outdated. Assuming the `index.html.erb` file is under a controller and a view called *patients*.
In rails 3 you would do it like this:

```
match "/" => "patients#index"
```